# Gradient of vector and scalar

Tags: derivatives, vector-analysis, scalar-fields

I have gotten the task of finding the gradient of f with respect to $\overline{x}$. The function is $f(\overline{x}) = \overline{x}^T\overline{x}+c$, where $\overline{x}$ is a vector and c is a scalar.

I know I have to derive it to find the gradient, and so far I have come to the derivative being $2\overline{x}$ since $\overline{x}^T\overline{x}=2\overline{x}$. The only part I am unsure about is what happens with the scalar? Is it just going to be 0, hence the gradient will just become $2\overline{x}$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, of course. $f(x+h)=(x+h)^T(x+h)+c=f(x)+2x^Th$.

Comment: Where does the $h$ you're using come from? Is it a way of rewriting vectors?

Comment: It's the definition of the gradient: $f(x+h)=f(x)+(\nabla f)h+o(h)$.